# Vim editor entities tagging/annotation tool

Tags: vimscript, syntax-highlighting, selection, plugin

I'm looking for a word/sentence annotation tool/plugin to be used INSIDE vim editor. Specifically I'm looking for a cli tool NER (named entity) tagging. Any idea/suggestion/tip?

By example, I would like to select a word or a list of contiguous words (using all vim conveniences) associating them to a a tag/label, say from a menu of tags (read form a config file, TBD).

The tagged text would be coloured with a nice background color and the file would be saved in a desired (configurable format). By example I would tag each NER span with a format like

```
[entity text span literal](entity_name)
```

By example, suppose I edit in vim a .txt or .yaml format (input) like this:

**Original file (without tagging)**

```yaml
  - intent: body_temperature_data
    examples: |
      - il termometro misura 36.3 gradi
      - 36.9
      - 35.9
      - 35,9
      - la temperatura è di 36 e 7 gradi
      - 36 , 8
```

**Tagged file: desired output file**

I want to tag some numbers are entity `body_temperature`, saving the file (in output) like this:

```yaml
  - intent: body_temperature_data
    examples: |
      - il termometro misura [36.3](body_temperature) gradi
      - [36.9](body_temperature)
      - [35.9](body_temperature) gradi
      - temperatura: [35,9](body_temperature)
      - la temperatura è di [36 e 7](body_temperature) gradi
      - [36 , 8](body_temperature)
```

**Tagged file: visualization in NORMAL mode**

[image]

Visually, during editing inside vim, I would like to see tagged words (numbers in the example) visualized with a background color (changing for each (preselected from a menu) label).

Example of visualization with web-based interface:

[image]

See visualization examples:

- https://github.com/doccano/doccano
- https://the-examples-book.com/prodigy/introduction

I guess one could realize al this coding a plugin in vimscript.

> I have in mind a similar example, the plugin https://github.com/elzr/vim-json to escape double quotes in editing JSON. In that case when you are editing the current line, double quotes are visible, otherwise aren't. In analogy:

- **when in INSERT mode**
  I would like to edit full text LINE
- **whereas, when in NORMAL mode**
  I would like to tag with the above mentioned experience (selecting&
  tag). By example: the cursor is INSIDE a word or I selected a span pf text in VISUAL mode, afterwad, maybe with a special key, I display a menu with all possible enitiy labels and I chose a label from menu, tagging the text.

> BTW, related question: [How to replace selected text T with some function(T), using a keyboard shortcut?](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34823/how-to-replace-selected-text-t-with-some-functiont-using-a-keyboard-shortcut/34824#34824)

Any suggestion is welcome.
Thanks

Comment: Well, you'll probably want to start with `:h conceal` and `:h 'conceallevel'`. That's Vim's mechanism for showing/hiding text. Note that you get "show concealed text when cursor is on the same line" behavior for free with this which is not the same as "show concealed text when editing" but perhaps an acceptable substitute.

Comment: @BLayer there’s an option concealcursor

Comment: I updated the question with a screenshot to better explain desired visualization in normal mode

Comment: You mention vim-json revealing double quotes _when you are editing_ but it reveals things regardless of mode as long as the cursor is on the line...I just tried it. (The `'concealcursor'` setting that DBK mentioned which could produce the "while editing only" behavior for the cursor line is explicitly unset).

Comment: @BLayer elzr/vim-json plugin, in INSERT mode: it allows to edit the line showing the real underling full json text (visualizing double quotes). Back to my question, I would like: in NORMAL mode: to see colorized tagged spans (e.g. `36.9` with yellow background color ); In INSERT mode to see/edit the corresponding tagged syntax, (eg. `[36.9](body_temperature)` )

Comment: I don't see that behavior out of the box so you must have some setting that enables it. Anyways, now it's clear what you're going for.

Comment: yes I guess I need to develop a vimscript program (a plugin) to do the job :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I answer myself, just to share a solution I'm working on:

- Entities visualization

  I developed a vim plugin to highlight words or sentences with a nice
  colorized background:

  https://github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim
- Entities Annotation

  I solved implementing a plugin that associates function keys
  to macros that allow to "decorate" a span of text with the `[]()` entity annotation syntax:

  https://github.com/solyarisoftware/nera.vim
- what is missing is the `conceal` behavior mentioned in comments.

Any comment/improvement here or on the plugin repo is absolutely welcome!