# How to replace selected text T with some function(T), using a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: vimscript, replace, cursor, selection

I want to annotate words /sentences for a "named entity recognition" purpose; inside a text file, I want to annotating words or sentences with this format `[pattern](label)`:

```
[a word where the cursor is or a selected sentence, a span](entity_name)
```

Suppose I have this text file:

```yaml
  # untagged.yaml
  - intent: body_temperature_data
    examples: |
      - il termometro misura 36.3 gradi
      - 36.9
      - 35,9
      - la temperatura è di 36 e 7 gradi
      - 36 , 8
```

I want by example to tag decimal numbers assigning the entity `body_temperature` to each of them, transforming the original file in this one:

```yaml
  # after_tagging.yaml
  - intent: body_temperature_data
    examples: |
      - il termometro misura [36.3](body_temperature) gradi
      - [36.9](body_temperature)
      - temperatura: [35,9](body_temperature)
      - la temperatura è di [36 e 7](body_temperature) gradi
      - [36 , 8](body_temperature)
```

What I need is a vim way to quickly substitute this line:

```
  - il termometro misura 36.3 gradi
```

in this line:

```
  - il termometro misura [36.3](body_temperature) gradi
```

Now, suppose I'm with cursor inside a word (a number in fact):

```
36.3
```

I want to substitute the (selected) word or sentence, with a keyboard shortcut in

```
[36.3](body_temperature)
```

So the original pattern `36.3` would be "decorated" with `[pattern](label)`

I know the basic substitute command:

```
s/selected_pattern/replace
```

and in this special case I want to do something like

```
s/pattern/[pattern](label)
```

But i do not know the syntax to make this replacement, maybe something like this (still not working):

```
'<,'>s/'<,'>/[\0](body_temperature)
```

- let assume `body_temperature` is in a short list of options (label_1, label_2, label_N) maybe stored in a vimscript variable I can assign.
- I would like to trigger the substitution with a keyboard shortcut (e.g. F1 key).

How can I do that?

BTW, that's part of the bigger problem here detailed:
[Vim editor entities tagging/annotation tool](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/34821/vim-editor-entities-tagging-annotation-tool)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Normal mode

### with the `:substitute` command.

```
nnoremap <leader>t :s/\%#\<<c-r><c-a>\>/[&]()/<cr>f(a
```

The trick is to use `<c-r><c-a>` which will insert the `:h <cWORD>` under the cursor, i.e non-whitespace characters. `<c-r><c-w>` would insert the `<cword>`, which respects `:h 'iskeyword'`, and would therefore (with default values) not contain decimals in floating numbers.

`:h \%#` start the match at the cursor position, so only the current occurrence of the pattern matches. This means the mapping will fail if the cursor is not on the first character of the word.

`:h \<`and `\>` match the beginning and end of a word. It's probably unecessary here.

Finally, the `&` in the string part represents the matched pattern, `<cr>` launches the command.

`f(a` places the cursor in insert mode between parentheses.

### "simple" way

```
nnoremap <leader>t ciW[<c-o>P]()<left>
```

`ciw]`: delete the  under the cursor and insert `[`.

`<c-o>P`: paste what was just deleted before the cursor

`]()`: insert the rest of the decoration

`<left>`: go between parenthesis

## Visual mode

```
vnoremap <leader>t :s/\%V.*\%V./[&]()/<cr>f(a
```

The difference is the match pattern: `\%V.*\%V.` matches the visual selection (:h `\%V`).

## Setting mappings for each label

This script creates a mapping `<leader>tX` for each 'label' in the 's:labels' variable, `X` being a number.
`printf` is a convenient way to pass a string to the `execute` command.

```
let s:labels = ["label1", "label2", "label3"]
for i in range(len(s:labels))
  exe printf("vnoremap <leader>t%d :s/\\%%V.*\\%%V./[&](%s)/<cr>n:nohl<cr>f)", i+1, s:labels[i])
  exe printf("nnoremap <leader>t%d ciW[<c-o>P](%s)<esc>", i+1, s:labels[i])
endfor
```

`n:nohl<cr>f)` tries to place the cursor after the label. It will fail if a `)` is in the pattern.

Comment: you are a vim-genius! I needed much time to read and understand your suggestions. Chapeau and thanks for great explanations. A small variant of your "simple" mode, when you want to annotate next two words from the current cursor: `:nnoremap <F2> c2W[<c-o>P]()<left>` . A lot to learn myself. To be continued...

Comment: I usually try to avoid numbers in this context in favor of operators for consistency. Thanks for your compliment, I appreciate -- however, I don't think I deserve being called a 'Vim genius' (yet). There's many of them on this forum, from whom I learned a few skills that helped me write this answer. Enjoy your vim journey!

Comment: Thx! BTW, your multi-label "setting mappings" inspired me to code the following idea: 
I want to realize a command like `:MyPluginSetFunctionKeyLabel F2 label2`. The command will do `exe printf("vnoremap <F2> :s...)` in that way user can dynamically/on-the fly set-up a single function key to do the visual/byword substitution. I I'll publish the plugin I'll acknowledge you. Maybe the plugin will be complementary to https://github.com/solyarisoftware/Highlight.vim

Comment: mentioned you @Biggybi in acknowledgements section of the plugin I just made (super draft), inspired by your examples: https://github.com/solyarisoftware/nesa.vim

Comment: @GiorgioRobino That's nice, thank you. I'll check that out as soon as I can :)

Comment: ERRATA CORRIGE: the name of plugin I made, inspired by @biggybi examples (thanks again) is: https://github.com/solyarisoftware/nera.vim